# Can Visual Studio 2013 use a different vcxproj for different Solution Configurations?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm using a shared c++ (static) library project (vcxproj) that I have no control over. My code has a few project configurations that depend on the shared library. Normally I would I add an additional project configuration to the shared library if I need it to build with different settings. But this has proven impossible so I've taken a drastic route of creating a second vcxproj for the shared library. Now I need my solution to only use the new custom project (sharedlib2) for only one solution configuration and not the other.

The issue at the moment seems to be that adding dependencies to the client project isn't per configuration. So there are always two dependencies.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Just use the "cloned" vcxproj for *all* your configurations and ignore the original vcxproj ... ?

Comment: The shared library gets updated so cloning isn't really an option unless I want to repeat this step over and over.

Comment: But you *will* have to update your modified configurations anyway ??